# Understanding core.async merge, in Clojure vs ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm experimenting with `core.async` on Clojure and ClojureScript, to try and understand how `merge` works. In particular, whether `merge` makes any values put on input channels available to take **immediately** on the merged channel.

I have the following code:

```
(ns async-merge-example.core
  (:require
   #?(:clj [clojure.core.async :as async] :cljs [cljs.core.async :as async])
   [async-merge-example.exec :as exec]))

(defn async-fn-timeout
  [v]
  (async/go
    (async/<! (async/timeout (rand-int 5000)))
    v))

(defn async-fn-exec
  [v]
  (exec/exec "sh" "-c" (str "sleep " (rand-int 5) "; echo " v ";")))

(defn merge-and-print-results
  [seq async-fn]
  (let [chans (async/merge (map async-fn seq))]
    (async/go
      (while (when-let [v (async/<! chans)]
               (prn v)
               v)))))
```

When I try `async-fn-timeout` with a large-ish `seq`:

```
(merge-and-print-results (range 20) async-fn-timeout)
```

For both Clojure **and** ClojureScript I get the result I expect, as in, results start getting printed pretty much immediately, with the expected delays.

However, when I try `async-fn-exec` with the same `seq`:

```
(merge-and-print-results (range 20) async-fn-exec)
```

For ClojureScript, I get the result I expect, as in results start getting printed pretty much immediately, with the expected delays. However for Clojure even though the `sh` processes are executed concurrently (subject to the size of the `core.async` thread pool), the results appear to be initially delayed, then mostly printed all at once!  I can make this difference more obvious by increasing the size of the seq e.g. `(range 40)`

Since the results for `async-fn-timeout` are as expected on both Clojure and ClojureScript, the finger is pointed at the differences between the Clojure and ClojureScript implementation for `exec`..

But I don't know why this difference would cause this issue?

Notes:

- These observations were made in WSL on Windows 10
- The source code for `async-merge-example.exec` is below
- In `exec`, the implementation differs for Clojure and ClojureScript due to differences between Clojure/Java and ClojureScript/NodeJS.

```
(ns async-merge-example.exec
  (:require
   #?(:clj [clojure.core.async :as async] :cljs [cljs.core.async :as async])))

; cljs implementation based on https://gist.github.com/frankhenderson/d60471e64faec9e2158c

; clj implementation based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292625/how-to-perform-non-blocking-reading-stdout-from-a-subprocess-in-clojure

#?(:cljs (def spawn (.-spawn (js/require "child_process"))))

#?(:cljs
   (defn exec-chan
     "spawns a child process for cmd with args. routes stdout, stderr, and
      the exit code to a channel. returns the channel immediately."
     [cmd args]
     (let [c (async/chan), p (spawn cmd (if args (clj->js args) (clj->js [])))]
       (.on (.-stdout p) "data"  #(async/put! c [:out  (str %)]))
       (.on (.-stderr p) "data"  #(async/put! c [:err  (str %)]))
       (.on p            "close" #(async/put! c [:exit (str %)]))
       c)))

#?(:clj
   (defn exec-chan
     "spawns a child process for cmd with args. routes stdout, stderr, and
      the exit code to a channel. returns the channel immediately."
     [cmd args]
     (let [c (async/chan)]
       (async/go
         (let [builder (ProcessBuilder. (into-array String (cons cmd (map str args))))
               process (.start builder)]
           (with-open [reader (clojure.java.io/reader (.getInputStream process))
                       err-reader (clojure.java.io/reader (.getErrorStream process))]
             (loop []
               (let [line (.readLine ^java.io.BufferedReader reader)
                     err (.readLine ^java.io.BufferedReader err-reader)]
                 (if (or line err)
                   (do (when line (async/>! c [:out line]))
                       (when err (async/>! c [:err err]))
                       (recur))
                   (do
                     (.waitFor process)
                     (async/>! c [:exit (.exitValue process)]))))))))
       c)))

(defn exec
  "executes cmd with args. returns a channel immediately which
   will eventually receive a result map of 
   {:out [stdout-lines] :err [stderr-lines] :exit [exit-code]}"
  [cmd & args]
  (let [c (exec-chan cmd args)]
    (async/go (loop [output (async/<! c) result {}]
                (if (= :exit (first output))
                  (assoc result :exit (second output))
                  (recur (async/<! c) (update result (first output) #(conj (or % []) (second output)))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Clojure implementation uses blocking IO in a single thread. You are first reading from stdout and then stderr in a loop. Both do a blocking `readLine` so they will only return once they actually finished reading a line. So unless your process creates the same amount of output to stdout and stderr one stream will end up blocking the other one.

Once the process is finished the `readLine` will no longer block and just return `nil` once the buffer is empty. So the loop just finishes reading the buffered output and then finally completes explaining the "all at once" messages.

You'll probably want to start a second thread that deals reading from stderr.

`node` does not do blocking IO so everything happens async by default and one stream doesn't block the other.

Comment: I don't think this is correct - whilst I am indeed using blocking IO, core.async executes code in `go` blocks using a pool of 8 threads. I can verify this when I execute the Clojure implementation, as I see 8 concurrent `dash` processes started immediately when I run the code. This confirms that the work is done in parallel. That said, what I can't account for, is the apparent delay in printing any results, even though `sh` processes start immediately...

Comment: You can run things in parallel just fine but each individual async/go will still block itself. Try adding a prn or so before the `(if (or line err)` line, you should see that no progress is made until both stdout/stderr receive a full line or the process exits.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean re: stdout/stderr, but in any case, I removed all the code relating to stderr, and I still get the same delay in printing. Further, I added `(println "process finished for " cmd " with args " args)` immediately after `(.waitFor process)`, and I see that output immediately when running.. that would suggest the cause is something to do with the core.async channel used to communicate the `:exit`?